# Json.NET constructing JSON with object initializers

Tags: c#, json.net, c#-7.0

I want to construct Json.NET object using object initializers for collections.

I can do:

```
JObject jsonObject = new JObject { { "Date", DateTime.Now }, { "obj", new JObject { { "string", "bla" } } } };
```

Now I want to do for example:

```
var j=new HashSet<int> { 5 };
JObject jsonObject = new JObject { { "hashset", j } };
```

But I get an error because there is no implicit conversion from HashSet to JToken

This works:

```
var j=new HashSet<int> { 5 };
JObject jsonObject = new JObject { { "hashset", JToken.FromObject(j) } };
```

but gets very verbose for complex construction.

Unfortunately I can't use extension methods to add an implicit conversion from HashSet to JToken which would have been probably ideal.

Any other ways to solve this ?

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Take a step back and explain to us your underlying problem. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: no it's not an XY problem, why not read the question instead of throwing this back

Comment: This is a little over my head so I'm not sure if this is any better, but what if you 'tokenized' when you create the HashSet? `JToken t = JToken.FromObject(new { j = new HashSet<int> { 5 } });` Then `JObject jsonObject = new JObject { { "hashset", t } };`.

Comment: thx, I already have that above, the whole point of this question is to try to allow the very concise syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are utilizing the [collection initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers), since `JObject` implements `IEnumerable` and has `Add` method with the following signature:

```
public void Add(string propertyName, JToken value)
```

So all you need is to create `Add` extension method with the appropriate signature:

```
namespace Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
{
    public static class JsonExtensions
    {
        public static void Add(this JObject target, string propertyName, object value) =>
            target.Add(propertyName, JToken.FromObject(value));
    }
}
```