# Cannot add new elements to Json Array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a configuration Json file that contains a List of dictionaries.

```
{
  "Hardware": [
    {
      "Name": "name1",
      "Model": "model1"
    },
    {
      "Name": "name2",
      "Model": "model2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am importing this Json into a variable using Newtonsoft.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public JObject Parameters;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText("../../configuration.json"))
            using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
            {
                Parameters = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This seem to work well and I can do things like:

```
`Parameters["Hardware"][0]["Name"].ToString()`   -> returns "name1"
```

Now, I have two string variables with a new name and a new model (this variables come from a loop that iterates over a DataGridView, but that's not relevant to the question)

```
string Name = "name3";
string Model = "model3";
```

Following this question [Creating JSON on the fly with JObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246716/creating-json-on-the-fly-with-jobject)  I have created a JToken containing this two variables, but I'm not sure how can I add them to `Parameters["Hardware"]`

I create a new JObject containing this name and model:

```
dynamic Aux = new JObject();
Aux.Name = "name3";
Aux.Model = "model3";
```

But if I try to do:

```
Parameters["Hardware"].Add(Aux);
```

It complains that `JToken does not contain a definition for Add`
I'm not sure why `Parameters["Hardware"]` is a JToken and not a JArray.

I tried doing something Hacky like:

```
Parameters["Hardware"] = (JArray)Parameters["Hardware"];
Parameters["Hardware"].Add(Aux);
```

But the compiler still complains about `Parameters["Hardware"]` being a JToken and won;t let me compile.

This is quite a basic thing, so I'm sure I might be doing something wrong and an easy solution exists, I just cannot figure it out.

At the end I want to have Parameters["Hardware"] like

```
{
  "Hardware": [
    {
      "Name": "name1",
      "Model": "model1"
    },
    {
      "Name": "name2",
      "Model": "model2"
    },
    {
      "Name": "name3",
      "Model": "model3"
    }
  ]
}
```

So I can export it back to a Json file.

So far I only needed to read the data from the Json or modify it, which works well, but now that I have to add elements is where I'm facing some trouble.

I am happy to change the way I read the file, maybe storing it as a JObject is not the best. So any suggestion on how to end up with a list of dictionaries with added elements is welcome.

Comment: You are getting that error because the indexer [`Parameters["Hardware"]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Item_1.htm) is **declared** to return an object of type [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) and `JToken` has no `Add()` method.  You need to cast to `JArray` like so `((JArray)Parameters["Hardware"]).Add(Aux)`.  See: [JContainer, JObject, JToken and Linq confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38558844/3744182).

Comment: I'll try that. But why is no directly a JArray and I need an explicit cast? In the json file, Hardware clearly contains an Array, so it should be casted accordingly by the parser.

Comment: Because the **declared** return type of `Parameters["Hardware"]` is `JToken`, which is the abstract base class for `JArray`, `JObject`, `JValue` and so on.  Since `Parameters["Hardware"]` could return any type of JSON token, the return value needs to be typed that way.  If you are expecting it to be an array you need to cast it to the subclass.

Comment: ok, your proposed solution works. If you add it as an answer I'll be happy to accept it

Comment: Have you considered using a proper statically typed class, then serializing and deserializing to `List<YourClass>`

Comment: Yes I have, the problem I found with classes is that they create a json with all the fields. My classes have many fields and only some hould come from the configuration or be exported as configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that error because the [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) indexer [`Parameters["Hardware"]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Item_1.htm) is **declared** to return an object of type [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm):

> ```
> public JToken this[
>   string propertyName
> ] { get; set; }
> ```

And `JToken`, which is the abstract base class for `JArray`, `JObject`, `JValue` and so on, has no `Add()` method.  You need to downcast to `JArray`, which does have an [`Add()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray_Add.htm) method, like so

```
((JArray)Parameters["Hardware"]).Add(Aux);
```

Since c# is [(mostly) statically typed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36114451/3744182) and the indexer is declared to return `JToken` you can only use the methods of the abstract base class `JToken`.  You must downcast to `JArray` to use `JArray` methods.

For a discussion of the LINQ to JSON type hierarchy see [JContainer, JObject, JToken and Linq confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38558844/3744182).

Answer (score -2):

try this..
it work for me just add it after last element in json object using JObject class.

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText("../../configuration.json"))
            using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
            {
                var Parameters = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
                dynamic Aux = new JObject();
                Aux.Name = "name3";
                Aux.Model = "model3";
                Parameters["Hardware"].Last.AddAfterSelf(Aux);
            }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).